# html5 tel link fired twice on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm facing a weird problem with a tel link in my Ionic cross-platform application.
When I click on the link, the iOS confirmation ('cancel' or 'call') is opened but few seconds after, it pops a second time.

[image]

```
<a ng-click="vm.trackPhoneCall()" 
   data-rel="external" 
   href="tel:{{ vm.intervention.client.phone }}"
   class="row button button-positive ion-ios-telephone">
     <br/>Appeler
</a>
```

How can I avoid this behaviour ?

It seems like the button is still pressed when the confirmation pops the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution ! Just add the attribute data-tap-disabled="true" to the div. Unfortunately, I still don't know what interfered with ionic tap system in this code.

```
<a data-tap-disabled="true"
   ng-click="vm.trackPhoneCall()" 
   data-rel="external" 
   href="tel:{{ vm.intervention.client.phone }}"
   class="row button button-positive ion-ios-telephone">
     <br/>Appeler
</a>
```